# "undefined method `deleted_at=' for #<Spree::User", even though this column exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot, spree

When I do a `create(:user)` in my tests I get this error: `undefined method deleted_at=' for #<Spree::User`.
It happens in all of my tests that try to do `create(:user)`.

This is what happens when I throw in a byebug:

```
$ rspec ./spec/models/spree/permission_sets/restricted_stock_transfer_display_spec.rb:40

  1) Spree::PermissionSets::RestrictedStockTransferDisplay when not activated
     Failure/Error: let(:user) { create :user }
     ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
       PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column spree_users.deleted_at does not exist
       LINE 1: ..."spree_users"."email" = 'darby@tremblay.name' AND "spree_use...
                                                                    ^
       : SELECT  1 AS one FROM "spree_users" WHERE ("spree_users"."email" = 'darby@tremblay.name' AND "spree_users"."deleted_at" IS NULL) LIMIT 1
```

**user_factory.rb**

```
require 'spree/testing_support/sequences'
require 'spree/testing_support/factories/role_factory'
require 'spree/testing_support/factories/address_factory'

FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :user, class: Spree.user_class do
    email { generate(:random_email) }
    login { email }
    password 'secret'
    password_confirmation { password }
    authentication_token { generate(:user_authentication_token) } if Spree.user_class.attribute_method? :authentication_token


     # [cut...]    

  end
end
```

**deleted_at is present in the database**

```
$ psql Solidus_test
psql (9.4.5)

Solidus_test=# \d spree_users

Table "public.spree_users"
             Column         |            Type             |                        Modifiers
    ------------------------+-----------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------

     deleted_at             | timestamp without time zone |
```

**But not present in Spree::User.column_names**

If I throw in a `byebug` in the test before `create(:user)` I discover this:

```
(byebug) Spree::User.column_names

["id", "encrypted_password", .....]
```

^  No "deleted_at"

Any tips to how I might get this rolling? Why can I see 'deleted_at' using `psql` but not when using `Spree::User.column_names`?

**Yes, I am connecting to Solidus_test:**

```
$ grep 'test'  config/database.yml -A2
test:
  <<: *default
  database: Solidus_test
```

Checking the test environment outside the rspec loop reveals that `deleted_at` is present:

```
✗ RAILS_ENV=test r c
Running via Spring preloader in process 4092
Loading test environment (Rails 4.2.5)
irb: warn: can't alias context from irb_context.
2.2.3 :001 > Spree::User.column_names
 => ["id", "encrypted_password", "password_salt", "email", "remember_token", "persistence_token", 
"reset_password_token", "perishable_token", "sign_in_count", "failed_attempts", "last_request_at", 
"current_sign_in_at", "last_sign_in_at", "current_sign_in_ip", "last_sign_in_ip", "login", 
"ship_address_id", "bill_address_id", "authentication_token", "unlock_token", "locked_at", 
"reset_password_sent_at", "created_at", "updated_at", "spree_api_key", "remember_created_at", 
"deleted_at", "confirmation_token", "confirmed_at", "confirmation_sent_at"]
```

Comment: Which line/lines is the error happening on? Please add any lines that you have not already added.

Comment: Hi Adrian, I've updated the question. It happens when `create(:user)` is executed. I triggered it by stopping the test with byebug and typed it myself.

Comment: Where do you assign the `deleted_at`? Can you include that code?

Comment: @MichalSzyndel I don't assign `deleted_at` anywhere. There is a query being made when I run `create(:user)`: `..."deleted_at" IS NULL) LIMIT 1` . I have not figured out what causes that query yet.

Comment: Well, then this is the first step. Take look at your factory, maybe it's set there. `deleted_at=` method is not available on rails models.

Comment: @martins Please try running `bundle exec rake db:test:prepare RAILS_ENV=test`. This will reset the DB. I know it might sound a bit silly, but can you check if you are indeed connecting to `Solidus_test ` DB in your `database.yml`. If you on Rails >= 4.1, you can simply run `bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had forgot to update something when I copied the `spec/spec_helper` from the solidus gem.

I fixed the spree_users.deleted_at bug by loading the correct environment:

```
require File.expand_path("../dummy/config/environment", __FILE__) 22
```

Should have been:

```
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
```

Thanks for all the suggestions, guys! :-D